# Is it possible to create a Stream from a File rather than loading the file contents into memory?

Tags: rust

I'm currently using the `rusoto_s3` lib to upload a file to S3. All the examples I have found do the same thing: Open a file, read the full contents of the file into memory (`Vec<u8>`), then convert the Vec into a `ByteStream` (which implements `From<Vec<u8>>`). Here is a code example:

```
fn upload_file(&self, file_path: &Path) -> FileResult<PutObjectOutput> {
    let mut file = File::open(file_path)?;
    let mut file_data: Vec<u8> = vec![];
    file.read_to_end(&mut file_data)?;

    let client = S3Client::new(Region::UsEast1);
    let mut request = PutObjectRequest::default();
    request.body = Some(file_data.into());

    Ok(client.put_object(request).sync()?)
}
```

This is probably acceptable for small files, but (I assume) this technique would break down as soon as you attempt to upload a file with a size greater than the available heap memory.

Another way to create a `ByteStream` is by [using this initializer](https://rusoto.github.io/rusoto/rusoto_core/struct.ByteStream.html#method.new) which accepts an object implementing the `Stream` trait. I would assume that `File` would implement this trait, but this does not appear to be the case.

#### My question(s):

Is there some type which can be constructed from a `File` which implements `Stream`? Is the correct solution to make my own tuple struct which wraps `File` and implements `Stream` itself, and is this implementation trivial? Is there another solution I'm not seeing, or am I simply misunderstanding how memory is allocated in the code above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there some type which can be constructed from a File which implements Stream?

No, unfortunately. Nothing built-in in `std`, `futures` or `tokio` can do this directly at the moment.

Due to the "detatched" nature of Stream's items, such an implementation would have to allocate a new owned buffer for every slice of incoming data and hand it over to the caller. That wouldn't be very efficient. Until the Rust language has generic associated type (GAT), which hopefully will be in next year, we then can satisfyingly address the problem. Check out [this `futures-rs` ticket](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/issues/2006) and [Niko's async interview #2](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2019/12/10/async-interview-2-cramertj-part-2/) for more detail.

That being said, there are use cases right now where a `Stream` facade on top of underlying IO is desirable and good enough.

> Is the correct solution to make my own tuple struct which wraps File and implements Stream itself, and is this implementation trivial?

For `futures-0.1` that the `rusoto` depends on, there are several ways to implement this:

- implement `Stream` trait for a struct that wraps a `Read`
- make use of `futures` utility functions such as `futures::stream::poll_fn`
- `tokio-codec-0.1` has an excellent `FramedRead` that has already implemented `Stream`

The third is surely the easiest:

```rust
use futures::stream::Stream;  // futures = "0.1.29"
use rusoto_core::{ByteStream, Region};  // rusoto_core = "0.42.0"
use rusoto_s3::{PutObjectOutput, PutObjectRequest, S3Client, S3};  // rusoto_s3 = "0.42.0"
use std::{error::Error, fs::File, path::Path};
use tokio_codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead};  // tokio-codec = "0.1.1"
use tokio_io::io::AllowStdIo;  // tokio-io = "0.1.12"

fn upload_file(file_path: &Path) -> Result<PutObjectOutput, Box<dyn Error>> {
    let file = File::open(file_path)?;
    let aio = AllowStdIo::new(file);
    let stream = FramedRead::new(aio, BytesCodec::new()).map(|bs| bs.freeze());

    let client = S3Client::new(Region::UsEast1);
    let mut request = PutObjectRequest::default();
    request.body = Some(ByteStream::new(stream));

    Ok(client.put_object(request).sync()?)
}
```

Comment: Is there a better answer for this in 2022? Looks like still no GATs.