# How to convert a Future into a Stream?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to use `async_std` to receive UDP datagrams from the network.

There is a `UdpSocket` that implements [`async recv_from`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv_from), this method returns a future but I need a `async_std::stream::Stream` that gives a stream of UDP datagrams because it is a better abstraction.

I've found [`tokio::net::UdpFramed`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/net/struct.UdpFramed.html) that does exactly what I need but it is not available in current versions of tokio.

Generally speaking the question is how do I convert `Future`s from a given async function into a `Stream`?

Comment: It has benn moved to [`tokio-util`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.2.0/tokio_util/udp/struct.UdpFramed.html) crate.

Comment: @edwardw this seems like it could be an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a single item, use [`FutureExt::into_stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.into_stream):

```
use futures::prelude::*; // 0.3.1

fn outer() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    inner().into_stream()
}

async fn inner() -> i32 {
    42
}
```

For a stream from a number of futures generated by a closure, use [`stream::unfold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/fn.unfold.html):

```
use futures::prelude::*; // 0.3.1

fn outer() -> impl Stream<Item = i32> {
    stream::unfold((), |()| async { Some((inner().await, ())) })
}

async fn inner() -> i32 {
    42
}
```

---

In your case, you can use `stream::unfold`:

```rust
use async_std::{io, net::UdpSocket}; // 1.4.0, features = ["attributes"]
use futures::prelude::*; // 0.3.1

fn read_many(s: UdpSocket) -> impl Stream<Item = io::Result<Vec<u8>>> {
    stream::unfold(s, |s| {
        async {
            let data = read_one(&s).await;
            Some((data, s))
        }
    })
}

async fn read_one(s: &UdpSocket) -> io::Result<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut data = vec![0; 1024];
    let (len, _) = s.recv_from(&mut data).await?;
    data.truncate(len);
    Ok(data)
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let s = UdpSocket::bind("0.0.0.0:9876").await?;

    read_many(s)
        .for_each(|d| {
            async {
                match d {
                    Ok(d) => match std::str::from_utf8(&d) {
                        Ok(s) => println!("{}", s),
                        Err(_) => println!("{:x?}", d),
                    },
                    Err(e) => eprintln!("Error: {}", e),
                }
            }
        })
        .await;

    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Generally speaking the question is how do I convert `Futures` from a given async function into a `Stream`?

There is [`FutureExt::into_stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/future/trait.FutureExt.html#method.into_stream), but don't let the name fool you; it is not a good fit for your situation.

> There is a `UdpSocket` that implements async `recv_from`, this method returns a future but I need a `async_std::stream::Stream` that gives a stream of UDP datagrams because it is a better abstraction.

It is *not* necessarily a better abstraction here.

Specifically, `async-std`'s [`UdpSocket::recv_from`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html#method.recv_from) returns a future that has output type of `(usize, SocketAddr)` — the size of the data received and the peer address. If you were to use `into_stream` to convert it to a stream, it would give you just that, not the data received.

> I've found `tokio::net::UdpFramed` that does exactly what I need but it is not available in current versions of tokio.

It has been moved to [`tokio-util`](https://docs.rs/tokio-util/0.2.0/tokio_util/udp/struct.UdpFramed.html) crate. Unfortunately, you can't (easily) use that either. It requires a [`tokio::net::UdpSocket`](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.11/tokio/net/struct.UdpSocket.html), which is not the same as [`async_std::net::UdpSocket`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.4.0/async_std/net/struct.UdpSocket.html).

You can, of course, use futures utility functions such as [`futures::stream::poll_fn`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/fn.poll_fn.html) or [`futures::stream::unfold`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/fn.unfold.html) to give `UdpSocket::recv_from` a [`futures::stream::Stream`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html) facade, but then what will you do with that? If you end up calling [`StreamExt::next`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.1/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.next) to poll a value out of it, you could have used `recv_from` directly.

It is only necessary to reach for `Stream` if some API you are using requires a `Stream` input, such as `rusoto`:

- [Is it possible to create a Stream from a File rather than loading the file contents into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428223/is-it-possible-to-create-a-stream-from-a-file-rather-than-loading-the-file-conte/59428936)